# Can not paste into Gnome Terminal from Netbeans

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, netbeans

When I copy something from another window then my terminal and want to paste it into my terminal (on the command line) the paste option in Edit is grayed out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work in GNOME Terminal 2.29.6.

I try to copy form netbeans into a terminal. If I paste it somewhere else, in gedit for example, it gets pasted. So it is copied.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> does not work.

Is this a settings of from some sort?

Comment: What terminal application are you using? Gnome-Terminal or another variety?

Comment: Just a gnome terminal: GNOME Terminal 2.29.6
Ubuntu 10.04 clean install (not an upgrade from 9.10)

Comment: The strange thing is, I only have this at home laptop. (sony vaio - fresh 10.04 install). At work (dell - also fresh 10.04 install) no problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to append a Shift when pasting into the Terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> Same with copying a selection only using a <kbd>C</kbd> instead:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd> is the escape sequence for shortcuts when using the Gnome Terminal.

Alternatively you can `Right Click`->`Paste`

Comment: Sounds logically, but this case it doesn't work. See my other comments.

Comment: You can configure your key bindings in your gnome terminal (Edit ->  Keyboard shortcuts ..) and make sure that Shift-Ctrl-C and Shift-Ctrl-V are bound (or whatever you like)

Comment: You can also use the mouse wheel button, if you have it....

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem with copying from Netbeans to terminal. It seems that when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Netbeans, it isn't copied in pure text format, so you can't paste it in terminal which require that kind of format (this is an assumption based on my experience ;) ).

So, how do I do it? Just copy from Netbeans, then paste it in some text editior, on example gedit, then copy it again and just paste in terminal.

Comment: The other answers below, currently with less votes, are easier. For example, just use middle click (as per user10244) or see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7769/keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-the-primary-selection

Comment: @eddy147: The answer by Marco Ceppi should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is not a bound combination in terminals. The terminal application ignores the keyboard event and passes it onto whatever's running. This is desirable because you don't *really* want the terminal window interfering with your keyboard events.

Right-click and click paste. Or use Primary Selection (highlight some text and middle-click).

Edit: I've just learned something! <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> will work if you want a keyboard input method. It's a primary-selection-based insert method, so just highlight and go.

Edit 2: I can't stop learning new things! As ændrük says, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works as a proper clipboard paste. So you've got lots of options. They're just not the standard key-combos.

Comment: +1 for `shift`+`insert`. It works pretty much anywhere, and is my preferred way to paste.  It'll paste the last thing in either of your clipboards (ie: if you highlighted something, it'll paste that, otherwise, it pastes the last thing you copied)

Comment: Actually, `Ctrl`+`V` _is_ bound in the nano terminal editor.

Answer (score 6):

Oli and user1974 suggested using Primary Selection (an X-Windows feature), but I needed these details to do so:

**1.) Highlight text in NetBeans** (don't worry about copying it)

**2.) Middle-click in GNOME Terminal** to paste it there

No other suggestions worked for me, but this worked like a charm.  There is a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188643) entered at netbeans.org for this.

Comment: Good answer. Here are a few more ways to do it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7769/keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-the-primary-selection

Comment: It's these little things - like having *two* copy buffers that keep me on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

tldr- use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> were keyboard shortcuts created for GUI applications. Apparently has something to do with [Xerox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C).

Before there was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.. there was

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

They were defined in 1987 by the [IBM Common User Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_User_Access)

These shortcuts often work in cases where the modern ones do not.. ie, in a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the system default keymappings - so you can ctrl+v into terminal.

[image: Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: This is the correct answer! Edit->Keyboard, and change the settings! bingo!

Comment: If you do this, you should also consider remapping the intr (formerly CTRL-C) command. I use `echo "stty intr \^b" >> ~/.bashrc` where b represents "break" -- or pick any other letter that isn't used on something important. One of the greatest productivity enhancements for me is making this simple change to the default copy and paste shortcuts in the terminal. I do it on all my computers first thing.

Comment: It seems as of Ubuntu 13.04, the shortcut options are no longer there!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with Rubymine, where I was unable to copy from Rubymine and paste into terminal with CTRL-SHIFT-V.  Given that I do this tens of times daily, I had little interest in copying to gedit every time and then copying to terminal, so I figured out a solution that doesn't require it:

http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/fix-it-ubuntu-ctrl-shift-v-wont-paste-into-terminal/

Short story: OpenJDK doesn't play nice with the clipboard.  I am guessing that this would apply to Netbeans as well as Rubymine since both run via a Java VM.

Comment: PhpStorm - same story. This is an openjdk issue. Moving to sun java resolved the problem.

Comment: @Dziamid thanks for the alternative to the horrible workarounds mentioned elsewhere in these answers.

Comment: @wbharding you might want to consider putting "switch to Sun Java" in your answer. I for one didn't bother reading the link but got the solution from Dziamid's comment. Might get you more upvotes.

Comment: Is there an OpenJDK bugreport on this?

Answer (score 3):

**Copy text by highlighting it with your mouse**.  Usually you can use Ctl+C or right click the selection select "copy" from the popup menu as well.

**Paste text by clicking your middle mouse button**.  Ctl+V also works in many places and so does Shift+Insert.

## What to do when that doesn't work

The problem occurs when different applications use different clipboards.  You will successfully copy the text to a clipboard in Application A, but when you go to Application B to paste, it will try paste from a different clipboard.  In Windows all applications use the same clipboard.

There are several solutions.  Probably the easiest one to get working is to install Parcellite.

### Install parcellite

```
sudo apt-get install parcellite
```

### Run parcellite

```
parcellite&
```

A clipboard icon will show up in the system tray.

### Use parcellite

1. Copy some text.
2. Click the clipboard icon in the system tray and select what you want from the menu.
3. Paste your text.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the text was not actually copied in the first place. If there is anything available to paste on the clipboard, then Edit -> Paste will be clickable.

In Gnome Terminal, the keyboard shortcut for pasting is usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: I thought so too, but it is copied.
I try to copy form netbeans into a terminal. If I paste it somewhere else, in gedit for example, it gets pasted. So it is copied.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Linux that sometimes de-selects copied information when trying to copy/paste between 2 different applications.  I recommend installing a clipboard manager, then you will see this bug in action.  Parcellite is my favorite.  If you are using Debian/Ubuntu paste "sudo apt-get install parcellite" (no quotes) into a terminal (ha,ha) or use Synaptic to install it.  This bug affects all programs, not just the terminal.

After you install and start Parcellite (Applications -> Accessories -> Parcellite) you will see a clipboard icon in your systray.  Recreate the bug, and then click the tray icon.  You will see that the info was copied but is grayed-out, i.e., not selected.  Click it to select it and then you can paste to your heart's content.  This is one of the most annoying bugs of all time and has been around for years.

Comment: nice suggestion, thx

Comment: It is a long term annoying problem. And it's intermittent. Sometimes paste works when it feels like it; other times is doesn't.  Those kinds of bugs with selective biting are the most infuriating.

Comment: It's funny...it still happens using GNOME 3 with GNOME Shell.  I'm lead to believe that it's really an Xserver problem (happens in KDE too!).  I wish it would get fixed already :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in gnome-terminal. You can try xfce4-terminal.

Comment: Thx for the alternative

Answer (score 1):

highlight text, middle click.

That's my favorite, quick, easy, works with other apps too.  You just have to be careful with your clicks as you can mess up the highlight.  (ie, you can't highlight the text, click around, highlight other text, and then hope to middle click the text from earlier.)