# Keyboard shortcut for pasting the primary selection

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, clipboard

Is there a standard or conventional keyboard shortcut for pasting the primary selection?

I'd like to select some text and go to another app to paste *without* trashing my clipboard contents.  I'd rather keep my fingers on the keyboard than move to the mouse, find the pointer, position it where I want, and middle-click.

If there's nothing conventional, or if it's application-specific and unsupported by many, is there a workaround to get this working globally? (Or at least in more applications.)

Comment: Possible same any distro: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard

Comment: FWIW, you can paste the primary selection from the keyboard (ie. without using mouse buttons) using shift-insert, and copy / paste the clipboard selection using ctrl-insert / ctrl-shift-insert

Comment: @JonathanHartley for me shift-insert  pastes from the clipboard not primary selection

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sending virtual keypresses doesn't work for me (see [comments](https://askubuntu.com/q/7775/1273)), but that answer inspired me to look for similar solutions.  Sending a "text" event with `xvkbd` ignores the current state of your physical keyboard:

```sh
sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -xsendevent -file - 2>/dev/null'
```

`xvkbd -text` uses a few backslash sequences, so rather than dance with escaping, `-file` works. Add `-delay 0` to enter the text without delay between the “keystrokes”. `xvkbd` also outputs some warning text about modifiers, but it appears to be irrelevant to this use (but I didn't want to see it in `~/.xsession-errors`).

I bound this to a shortcut using **System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**.

Note that you need to have xsel and xvkbd packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel xvkbd
```

Comment: Holy bananas!  It works!  Thats awesome. Ubuntu should set this up by default.

Comment: For me, `sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -file - 2>/dev/null'` works, -xsendevent had to get out to make it working.

Comment: By the way once more, I had to assign this command to a single key shortcut (luckily I have ThinkVantage button doing nothing on my Thinkpad - ctrl + alt + v behaved strangely and pasted only part of what was in `xsel`).

Comment: This works very well except for two problems. (1) I use a drop-down terminal (Guake) that I have set to hide on lose focus. Running this script removes focus temporarily from the terminal, causing it to hide. (2) It doesn't deal well with  UTF-8 characters double-byte characters. e.g. if I select "éòü", using the script prints "Ã©Ã²Ã¼".

Comment: It looks like the second bug is in `xvkbd`. `xsel` works fine with "éòü" in the primary selection, but `xvkbd` fails as the script above. (And also fails with`xvkbd -text "éòü"`, although here it prints nothing.)

Comment: Here on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, I did: Open "Keyboard" from Unity ( == Settings / Keyboard). Shortcuts tab, '+' for Add Shortcut, and assign `sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -xsendevent -file - 2>/dev/null'` as the command to my chosen key (`CTRL-ALT-V`). I also had to remove `-xsendevent`.

Comment: This works, but one less-than-ideal thing about it is that it behaves as if I had literally typed the selection in: there is a delay while the selected text gets entered character by character (vs instantly for a middle click), and undoing the paste also takes many steps.

Comment: I can recommend a variation that also works with international characters: `sh -c 'xsel | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 - | xvkbd -xsendevent -utf16 -file - 2>/dev/null'`. This requires the `iconv` package to be installed in addition to the other packages from the answer.

Comment: I am afraid this is X specific, i.e. does not work on Wayland

Comment: Solutions for Wayland would be welcome!

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for an answer for this very same question, and I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/640816/343650) that says that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> is working to paste the primary selection. I works for me. Simpler.

Comment: On Ubuntu by default [Shift+Insert paste the regular clipboard just like Ctrl+v](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123240/209677), not the primary selection. Which distro are you using?

Answer (score 8):

You can get this with the combined use of the programs
[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) 
([click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)) and 
[xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/xsel.1x.html)
([click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xsel)).

`xdotool` can simulate typing into a window; `xsel` outputs the
contents of the PRIMARY selection (by default); the following shell
one liner will do the trick:

```
 xdotool type `xsel`
```

To bind this to any key using the *System->Preferences->Keyboard
shortcuts* menu item it is necessary to wrap it in a shell invocation:

```
 sh -c 'xdotool type --clearmodifiers -- "`xsel`"'
```

Typing in `xdotool` will not work with some programs; see the notes in
the [xdotool documentation](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).

Comment: That won't work unless the active text box and cursor position is at that exact position, and it certainly isn't.  In fact, if this counts the window manager border, that will do my "middle-click on window title" action, which is completely different.

Comment: @Roger Thanks, corrected the text. I'm curious whether there's a better way to do this: I myself have been looking for a "paste"-key for quite some time...

Comment: Well, I appreciate the effort, but this still won't work.  If I wanted to worry about the mouse position, I'd just use the mouse in the first place. :)

Comment: @Roger: Got it correct second time round: xdotool+xsel does it. (Well, at least works for me.)

Comment: Needs to be `"$(xsel)"` to allow for spaces, but otherwise this seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Needs --clearmodifiers option, otherwise there's a race condition between releasing the keyboard shortcut and xdotool executing.  The xdotool in 10.04's repos isn't updated for this option, I had to [download](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) and build it myself.  However, --clearmodifiers seems to strangely affect the modifiers, and I don't see how, in the end, to make xdotool work for my keyboard shortcut (though it works great for virtually typing text).

Comment: In case it's not clear from my comment: I was testing with super(winkey)-v; without --clearmodifiers, super is still held down when xdotool types, and since I use that modifier key for most of my window management actions...

Comment: Oh, I see: I was using key "F9" for my tests...

Comment: I am afraid this is X specific, i.e. does not work on Wayland

Answer (score 4):

Calling `xdotool click --clearmodifiers 2` simulates clicking middle mouse button. This works much better than using xsel (at least for me). Altough you have to position your mouse before typing...

Answer (score 4):

Another xdotool suggestion, working in Debian Jessie 8.7 (Jan 2017):

```
xdotool click --delay 0 --clearmodifiers 2
```

- xdotool handles multi-byte strings (p.e. UTF-8), unlike xvkbd.
- `xdotool click` simulates an actual click, so you don't have to click yourself to paste at mouse position, as you would have if you used `xdotool type`, or xvkbd.

The only problem is that `--clearmodifiers` will "press" back any modifier (Ctrl/Alt/Shift/Meta) you use after simulating the click.  Even with `--delay 0` (instead of 12ms), the command takes a little to execute.  If you release the keys before it ends, your modifiers will be "pressed" again, and stuck there until you press and release the actual key once more.

So with this you have to be a bit "slow" (50ms?) to release your modifiers, if you're using any.

You can test this by setting up your keyboard shortcut, using it into a text editor, and then pressing a key (like `a`, or an arrow).  The letter should appear in lowercase.  If something else happens, you are too fast and a modifier is stuck (p.e. Shift if it's in caps, Ctrl if you selected all text, Alt if you opened a menu).  Press and release your modifiers again to reset them.

If you're too fast, you can use ilkerk's suggestion:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.3 && xdotool type --clearmodifiers --delay 0  "`xsel`"'
```

Then you have to release them in *less* than 300ms, and wait half a second for the text to appear.

Also, using `xdotool type` means you insert the text as if you where typing, at the text cursor position, and not the mouse pointer.  You can change it to `click` if you prefer the usual middle-click behaviour.

(made this post so newcomers don't have to piece the puzzle pieces spread in the comments again)

Comment: works for me in Arch Linux now

Comment: I am afraid this is X specific, i.e. does not work on Wayland

Answer (score 3):

**I had problems with the solutions that *simulate pasting* the `PRIMARY` selection, so instead I added a shortcut that *copies* the `PRIMARY` selection to the `CLIPBOARD`**. After using my shortcut I paste the `CLIPBOARD` in the usual way, with `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Shift+V`, or `Shift+Insert`, depending on the application.

The command to copy the `PRIMARY` selection to the `CLIPBOARD` is

```
sh -c 'xsel --output --primary | xsel --input --cliboard'
```

which I bind to `Ctrl+Insert` (arbitrary choice) in the Gnome shortcut settings under `System Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard`

**Summary of problems with other solutions:** I tried the `xsel | xvkbd ...` and `xsel | xdotool ...` solutions, but found they didn't work very well because they simulate *typing* the `PRIMARY` selection character by character, which is not the same as *pasting* it with middle click. Problems include: there's a long delay while a large selection gets inserted one character at a time; if you want to undo the "paste", you have to undo it character by character, which is slow; if you're using "dead keys" then everything gets messed up, e.g. "pasting" `"e` produces `ë`; the `xvkdb` doesn't handle unicode characters correctly.

**Warning:** This solution overwrites the existing `CLIPBOARD` contents, but the OP asked for solutions that preserve the existing `CLIPBOARD` contents.

Comment: Does this save the original clipboard contents & set it again afterwards? Or does it trash the original clipboard contents, thus failing the "*to paste without trashing my clipboard contents*" part of the question?

Comment: @Xen2050 yes, this trashes the CLIPBOARD. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: It's not that much harder to write a little shell script or one-liner that *switches* the contents of the X selection with the clipboard, using xsel (or xclip).  If you bind this to a key command, then by combining it with Ctrl+v you can effectively paste the X selection while preserving the existing clipboard contents.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and internet search didn't help me much. 
The problem simulating click 2 is annoying as OP mentioned.

The problem with the above proposed `xdotool` and xsel is when `xdotool` starts "typing" you are still pressing another key. That does not always result with any output. For example if you bind it to "insert" key then `xdotool` is sending keys while your finger is pressing "insert" key which causes nothing.

Below is a workaround, to bind it to a key press :

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.3 && xdotool type --clearmodifiers --delay 0  "`xsel`"'
```

it is not perfect but working. now you have 0.3 seconds to finish your selection of key press (and key up).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xclip`

Copy the content of `primary` to `clipboard` using the following command:

```
sh -c 'xclip -o -selection primary | xclip -selection clipboard'
```

You can bind this command to any keyboard shortcut of your preference. If you are using Gnome desktop environment you can do it by going to `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts` or search for `keyboard shortcuts` in case of other DE.

Now, you can paste the content in the usual way by `Ctrl-v` or `Ctrl-Shift-v`.

**HOWEVER** This will overwrite the previous content of your clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

In KDE on Debian Bullseye the default key combo seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.