# Keyboard shortcut for pasting on the GNOME Terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

We use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste stuff from clipboard, but this is not working on terminal window.

What is the keyboard shortcut to paste on the GNOME terminal?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V are the respective shortcuts. Another thing that also works with Linux (in general): if you mark a fragment of text, without any shortcut, you can paste it in by clicking the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Have you tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Why not just Ctrl + V ? I dont get it...

Comment: @user1767754 This shortcut is already used by most terminals to indicate that the next key should be inserted literally.  This allows for example to insert a raw Tab character into terminal.

Comment: [Shift] + [Insert] works for paste sometimes

Answer (score 59):

You have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into a terminal. Copy is similar; use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy from a terminal.

---

Arild's comment explains (edited a bit):

> Following tradition, some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(letter)</kbd> shortcuts are mapped to entering control characters in the terminal (see [How control characters map to keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards) on Wikipedia). That's why we cannot use them for copy and paste. The shortcuts can be overridden in Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts, but especially Ctrl+C is useful to keep assigned to the control character ETX, which is used to interrupt the current command.

Comment: Following tradition, some Ctrl+(letter) shortcuts are mapped to entering control characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards) in the terminal. That's why we cannot use them for copy and paste. The shortcuts can be overridden in Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts..., but especially Ctrl+C is useful to keep assigned to the control character ETX, which is used to interrupt the current command.

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for 'copy', <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for 'cut' and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for 'paste' also works on most places, including GNOME terminal.

Comment: `Shift+Insert` pastes "primary selection" (`xsel`).  `Ctrl+Shift+V` pastes clipboard (`xsel -b`) on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04, GNOME Terminal).

Answer (score 13):

Like said by others, Copy is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> as opposed to a normal text field.

So in short, just add shift to many other text editing shortcut to use it in the terminal.

Here are a couple examples:

Copy: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Paste: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Find: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Close terminal window: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Close all terminal windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

and etc.

Comment: (We're generally not supposed to use comments for +1, but I want to say this is an excellent first answer: concisely adds new info and improves on existing answers.)