# Copy-paste problem

Tags: clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not paste into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3541/can-not-paste-into-terminal)

I'm relatively new to linux.

My question is, why when I do ctrl+C (copy) in Eclipse, and then shift+insert (paste) in command line, there's nothing pasted?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl`+`shift` instead of just `shift` to paste ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the GNOME Terminal, the shortcut for paste is **Shift+Ctrl+V**. (See the Edit menu).

Answer (score 13):

There are actually multiple paste buffers (or clipboards if you prefer).

When you mark some text using the left mouse button, that text is immediately put in the primary paste buffer. You use the middle mouse button to paste from the primary buffer.

The secondary buffer is generally copied to by marking the text and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and pasted from by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, though these key bindings are only a convention; some applications require different key bindings.

The terminal has already mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>|<kbd>V</kbd> to mean something else, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>|<kbd>V</kbd> has been chosen for this instead.

There is also a third paste buffer, but this is rarely used.

Comment: what about Ctrl + insert and Shift + insert? Are these a third type of buffer?

Comment: @gasan I don't know of any applications that use Ctrl|Shift+Insert for copying and pasting. If I'm not mistaken, these are common keybindings in Windows, but I can't remember seeing them in Linux applications. At any rate, if any Linux app does accept them to mean copy and paste, they'll most likely be working on the secondary buffer.

Comment: Ctrl+ins and Shift+ins can be used probably in any linux application that supports copy/paste. It looks like you're right and they are working on the secondary buffer, the same as Ctrl+C, ctrl+v. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Possible ways to do that:

Right click

Middle Mouse button

Shift+ctrl+V