# Highlighting to Copy with Terminal

Tags: command-line, clipboard

I'm wondering if there is a terminal enhancement, or a way to make the terminal to where when I highlight over anything it auto copies whatever I highlight.  I know this is a feature in some terminal text editors (like grep or vi), but was wondering if there is compatibility somehow in the terminal itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Middle mouse button click will paste the highlighted text into the terminal (or wherever you can enter text).

For more detailed information on Multiple Paste Buffers see [geirha's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/107258/28369) in this question.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying this with right mouse click but didn't think to use the middle mouse button! D'oh :( Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Btw. please read the excellent linked answer, because it sheds some light on the different methods of copying & pasting.