# Why ctrl + v is not working in terminal

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not paste into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3541/can-not-paste-into-terminal)

Usually I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for pasting the copied content. But it is not working in terminal. Why it is disabled, Is there any alternative key board shortcut to do it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use shift with the normal keys in the terminal, ie <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, etc.

I think it's changed because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is meaningful to the terminal as an interrupt, so shift was added for all of them.

**Edit:**

I just realized that you when you said "disabled", you may not have meant it simply doesn't work.  If you right-click, and "paste" is actually disabled (ie, "grayed out"), then that would probably mean that the clipboard data is not  something that the terminal can handle, it doesn't exist, or it's read-only.