# UBUNTU 14.04 Right mouse click and paste (shift+ctrl+v or ctrl+v) does not work when pasting on to the terminal. HELP!

Tags: command-line, paste

I try to copy from the descriptions and paste the code into the terminal but it doesn't work. Even the rightmouse click does not work.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work even the right mouse click does not work.

What can I do pls?

UPDATE:
I found this answer (but is not for ubuntu 14.04):
https://askubuntu.com/a/113308/390077

Answer (score 2):

Select what you want to copy, then use the middle button of your mouse to paste. If you don't have a middle button, try pressing both mouse buttons at once.

In any case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> isn't supposed to work. The shortcut for pasting into a terminal after having copied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, I select the text by dragging with the left mouse button, press the right mouse button and select copy from the pop-up menu.

To paste, press the right mouse button and select paste from the pop-up menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found if you install Gnome terminal you can rightmouse click!

Comment: `gnome-terminal` is the standard terminal in Ubuntu...  What kind of Ubuntu are you running?